# need Help in windivert webfilter

Tags: filter

Hello every one i m trying to develop  web filter and i found Win Divert Samples 
here the code is i m trying to run in visual Studio 12 and got this error
        IntelliSense: argument of type "PVOID" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *"

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "windivert.h"

#define MAXBUF 0xFFFF
#define MAXURL 4096

/*
 * URL and blacklist representation.
 */
typedef struct
{
    char *domain;
    char *uri;
} URL, *PURL;
typedef struct
{
    UINT size;
    UINT length;
    PURL *urls;
} BLACKLIST, *PBLACKLIST;

/*
 * Pre-fabricated packets.
 */
typedef struct
{
    WINDIVERT_IPHDR  ip;
    WINDIVERT_TCPHDR tcp;
} PACKET, *PPACKET;
typedef struct 
{
    PACKET header;
    UINT8 data[];
} DATAPACKET, *PDATAPACKET;

/*
 * THe block page contents.
 */
const char block_data[] =
    "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
    "Connection: close\r\n"
    "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
    "\r\n"
    "<!doctype html>\n"
    "<html>\n"
    "\t<head>\n"
    "\t\t<title>BLOCKED!</title>\n"
    "\t</head>\n"
    "\t<body>\n"
    "\t\t<h1>BLOCKED!</h1>\n"
    "\t\t<hr>\n"
    "\t\t<p>This URL has been blocked!</p>\n"
    "\t</body>\n"
    "</html>\n";

/*
 * Prototypes
 */
static void PacketInit(PPACKET packet);
static int __cdecl UrlCompare(const void *a, const void *b);
static int UrlMatch(PURL urla, PURL urlb);
static PBLACKLIST BlackListInit(void);
static void BlackListInsert(PBLACKLIST blacklist, PURL url);
static void BlackListSort(PBLACKLIST blacklist);
static BOOL BlackListMatch(PBLACKLIST blacklist, PURL url);
static void BlackListRead(PBLACKLIST blacklist, const char *filename);
static BOOL BlackListPayloadMatch(PBLACKLIST blacklist, char *data,
    UINT16 len);

/*
 * Entry.
 */
int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    HANDLE handle;
    WINDIVERT_ADDRESS addr;
    UINT8 packet[MAXBUF];
    UINT packet_len;
    PWINDIVERT_IPHDR ip_header;
    PWINDIVERT_TCPHDR tcp_header;
    PVOID payload;
    UINT payload_len;
    PACKET reset0;
    PPACKET reset = &reset0;
    PACKET finish0;
    PPACKET finish = &finish0;
    PDATAPACKET blockpage;
    UINT16 blockpage_len;
    PBLACKLIST blacklist;
    unsigned i;
    INT16 priority = 404;       // Arbitrary.

    // Read the blacklists.
    if (argc <= 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s blacklist.txt [blacklist2.txt ...]\n",
            argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    blacklist = BlackListInit();
    for (i = 1; i < (UINT)argc; i++)
    {
        BlackListRead(blacklist, argv[i]);
    }
    BlackListSort(blacklist);

    // Initialize the pre-frabricated packets:
    blockpage_len = sizeof(DATAPACKET)+sizeof(block_data)-1;
    blockpage = (PDATAPACKET)malloc(blockpage_len);
    if (blockpage == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    PacketInit(&blockpage->header);
    blockpage->header.ip.Length   = htons(blockpage_len);
    blockpage->header.tcp.SrcPort = htons(80);
    blockpage->header.tcp.Psh     = 1;
    blockpage->header.tcp.Ack     = 1;
    memcpy(blockpage->data, block_data, sizeof(block_data)-1);
    PacketInit(reset);
    reset->tcp.Rst = 1;
    reset->tcp.Ack = 1;
    PacketInit(finish);
    finish->tcp.Fin = 1;
    finish->tcp.Ack = 1;

    // Open the Divert device:
    handle = WinDivertOpen(
            "outbound && "              // Outbound traffic only
            "ip && "                    // Only IPv4 supported
            "tcp.DstPort == 80 && "     // HTTP (port 80) only
            "tcp.PayloadLength > 0",    // TCP data packets only
            WINDIVERT_LAYER_NETWORK, priority, 0
        );
    if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: failed to open the WinDivert device (%d)\n",
            GetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("OPENED WinDivert\n");

    // Main loop:
    while (TRUE)
    {
        if (!WinDivertRecv(handle, packet, sizeof(packet), &addr, &packet_len))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "warning: failed to read packet (%d)\n",
                GetLastError());
            continue;
        }

        if (!WinDivertHelperParsePacket(packet, packet_len, &ip_header, NULL,
                NULL, NULL, &tcp_header, NULL, &payload, &payload_len) ||
            !BlackListPayloadMatch(blacklist, payload, (UINT16)payload_len))
        {
            // Packet does not match the blacklist; simply reinject it.
            if (!WinDivertSend(handle, packet, packet_len, &addr, NULL))
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "warning: failed to reinject packet (%d)\n",
                    GetLastError());
            }
            continue;
        }

        // The URL matched the blacklist; we block it by hijacking the TCP
        // connection.

        // (1) Send a TCP RST to the server; immediately closing the
        //     connection at the server's end.
        reset->ip.SrcAddr       = ip_header->SrcAddr;
        reset->ip.DstAddr       = ip_header->DstAddr;
        reset->tcp.SrcPort      = tcp_header->SrcPort;
        reset->tcp.DstPort      = htons(80);
        reset->tcp.SeqNum       = tcp_header->SeqNum;
        reset->tcp.AckNum       = tcp_header->AckNum;
        WinDivertHelperCalcChecksums((PVOID)reset, sizeof(PACKET), 0);
        if (!WinDivertSend(handle, (PVOID)reset, sizeof(PACKET), &addr, NULL))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "warning: failed to send reset packet (%d)\n",
                GetLastError());
        }

        // (2) Send the blockpage to the browser:
        blockpage->header.ip.SrcAddr       = ip_header->DstAddr;
        blockpage->header.ip.DstAddr       = ip_header->SrcAddr;
        blockpage->header.tcp.DstPort      = tcp_header->SrcPort;
        blockpage->header.tcp.SeqNum       = tcp_header->AckNum;
        blockpage->header.tcp.AckNum       =
            htonl(ntohl(tcp_header->SeqNum) + payload_len);
        WinDivertHelperCalcChecksums((PVOID)blockpage, blockpage_len, 0);
        addr.Direction = !addr.Direction;     // Reverse direction.
        if (!WinDivertSend(handle, (PVOID)blockpage, blockpage_len, &addr,
                NULL))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "warning: failed to send block page packet (%d)\n",
                GetLastError());
        }

        // (3) Send a TCP FIN to the browser; closing the connection at the 
        //     browser's end.
        finish->ip.SrcAddr       = ip_header->DstAddr;
        finish->ip.DstAddr       = ip_header->SrcAddr;
        finish->tcp.SrcPort      = htons(80);
        finish->tcp.DstPort      = tcp_header->SrcPort;
        finish->tcp.SeqNum       =
            htonl(ntohl(tcp_header->AckNum) + sizeof(block_data) - 1); 
        finish->tcp.AckNum       =
            htonl(ntohl(tcp_header->SeqNum) + payload_len);
        WinDivertHelperCalcChecksums((PVOID)finish, sizeof(PACKET), 0);
        if (!WinDivertSend(handle, (PVOID)finish, sizeof(PACKET), &addr, NULL))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "warning: failed to send finish packet (%d)\n",
                GetLastError());
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Initialize a PACKET.
 */
static void PacketInit(PPACKET packet)
{
    memset(packet, 0, sizeof(PACKET));
    packet->ip.Version = 4;
    packet->ip.HdrLength = sizeof(WINDIVERT_IPHDR) / sizeof(UINT32);
    packet->ip.Length = htons(sizeof(PACKET));
    packet->ip.TTL = 64;
    packet->ip.Protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    packet->tcp.HdrLength = sizeof(WINDIVERT_TCPHDR) / sizeof(UINT32);
}

/*
 * Initialize an empty blacklist.
 */
static PBLACKLIST BlackListInit(void)
{
    PBLACKLIST blacklist = (PBLACKLIST)malloc(sizeof(BLACKLIST));
    UINT size;
    if (blacklist == NULL)
    {
        goto memory_error;
    }
    size = 1024;
    blacklist->urls = (PURL *)malloc(size*sizeof(PURL));
    if (blacklist->urls == NULL)
    {
        goto memory_error;
    }
    blacklist->size = size;
    blacklist->length = 0;

    return blacklist;

memory_error:
    fprintf(stderr, "error: failed to allocate memory\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/*
 * Insert a URL into a blacklist.
 */
static void BlackListInsert(PBLACKLIST blacklist, PURL url)
{
    if (blacklist->length >= blacklist->size)
    {
        blacklist->size = (blacklist->size*3) / 2;
        printf("GROW blacklist to %u\n", blacklist->size);
        blacklist->urls = (PURL *)realloc(blacklist->urls,
            blacklist->size*sizeof(PURL));
        if (blacklist->urls == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "error: failed to reallocate memory\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    blacklist->urls[blacklist->length++] = url;
}

/*
 * Sort the blacklist (for searching).
 */
static void BlackListSort(PBLACKLIST blacklist)
{
    qsort(blacklist->urls, blacklist->length, sizeof(PURL), UrlCompare);
}

/*
 * Match a URL against the blacklist.
 */
static BOOL BlackListMatch(PBLACKLIST blacklist, PURL url)
{
    int lo = 0, hi = ((int)blacklist->length)-1;

    while (lo <= hi)
    {
        INT mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
        int cmp = UrlMatch(url, blacklist->urls[mid]);
        if (cmp > 0)
        {
            hi = mid-1;
        }
        else if (cmp < 0)
        {
            lo = mid+1;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}


/*
 * Read URLs from a file.
 */
static void BlackListRead(PBLACKLIST blacklist, const char *filename)
{
    char domain[MAXURL+1];
    char uri[MAXURL+1];
    int c;
    UINT16 i, j;
    PURL url;
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: could not open blacklist file %s\n",
            filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Read URLs from the file and add them to the blacklist: 
    while (TRUE)
    {
        while (isspace(c = getc(file)))
            ;
        if (c == EOF)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (c != '-' && !isalnum(c))
        {
            while (!isspace(c = getc(file)) && c != EOF)
                ;
            if (c == EOF)
            {
                break;
            }
            continue;
        }
        i = 0;
        domain[i++] = (char)c;
        while ((isalnum(c = getc(file)) || c == '-' || c == '.') && i < MAXURL)
        {
            domain[i++] = (char)c;
        }
        domain[i] = '\0';
        j = 0;
        if (c == '/')
        {
            while (!isspace(c = getc(file)) && c != EOF && j < MAXURL)
            {
                uri[j++] = (char)c;
            }
            uri[j] = '\0';
        }
        else if (isspace(c))
        {
            uri[j] = '\0';
        }
        else
        {
            while (!isspace(c = getc(file)) && c != EOF)
                ;
            continue;
        }

        printf("ADD %s/%s\n", domain, uri);

        url = (PURL)malloc(sizeof(URL));
        if (url == NULL)
        {
            goto memory_error;
        }
        url->domain = (char *)malloc((i+1)*sizeof(char));
        url->uri    = (char *)malloc((j+1)*sizeof(char));
        if (url->domain == NULL || url->uri == NULL)
        {
            goto memory_error;
        }
        strcpy(url->uri, uri);
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            url->domain[j] = domain[i-j-1];
        }
        url->domain[j] = '\0';

        BlackListInsert(blacklist, url);
    }

    fclose(file);
    return;

memory_error:
    fprintf(stderr, "error: memory allocation failed\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/*
 * Attempt to parse a URL and match it with the blacklist.
 *
 * BUG:
 * - This function makes several assumptions about HTTP requests, such as:
 *      1) The URL will be contained within one packet;
 *      2) The HTTP request begins at a packet boundary;
 *      3) The Host header immediately follows the GET/POST line.
 *   Some browsers, such as Internet Explorer, violate these assumptions
 *   and therefore matching will not work.
 */
static BOOL BlackListPayloadMatch(PBLACKLIST blacklist, char *data, UINT16 len)
{
    static const char get_str[] = "GET /";
    static const char post_str[] = "POST /";
    static const char http_host_str[] = " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: ";
    char domain[MAXURL];
    char uri[MAXURL];
    URL url = {domain, uri};
    UINT16 i = 0, j;
    BOOL result;
    HANDLE console;

    if (len <= sizeof(post_str) + sizeof(http_host_str))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    if (strncmp(data, get_str, sizeof(get_str)-1) == 0)
    {
        i += sizeof(get_str)-1;
    }
    else if (strncmp(data, post_str, sizeof(post_str)-1) == 0)
    {
        i += sizeof(post_str)-1;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    for (j = 0; i < len && data[i] != ' '; j++, i++)
    {
        uri[j] = data[i];
    }
    uri[j] = '\0';
    if (i + sizeof(http_host_str)-1 >= len)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (strncmp(data+i, http_host_str, sizeof(http_host_str)-1) != 0)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    i += sizeof(http_host_str)-1;

    for (j = 0; i < len && data[i] != '\r'; j++, i++)
    {
        domain[j] = data[i];
    }
    if (i >= len)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    if (j == 0)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    if (domain[j-1] == '.')
    {
        // Nice try...
        j--;
        if (j == 0)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    domain[j] = '\0';

    printf("URL %s/%s: ", domain, uri);

    // Reverse the domain:
    for (i = 0; i < j / 2; i++)
    {
        char t = domain[i];
        domain[i] = domain[j-i-1];
        domain[j-i-1] = t;
    }

    // Search the blacklist:
    result = BlackListMatch(blacklist, &url);

    // Print the verdict:
    console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if (result)
    {
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(console, FOREGROUND_RED);
        puts("BLOCKED!");
    }
    else
    {
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(console, FOREGROUND_GREEN);
        puts("allowed");
    }
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(console,
        FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE);
    return result;
}

/*
 * URL comparison.
 */
static int __cdecl UrlCompare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    PURL urla = *(PURL *)a;
    PURL urlb = *(PURL *)b;
    int cmp = strcmp(urla->domain, urlb->domain);
    if (cmp != 0)
    {
        return cmp;
    }
    return strcmp(urla->uri, urlb->uri);
}

/*
 * URL matching
 */
static int UrlMatch(PURL urla, PURL urlb)
{
    UINT16 i;

    for (i = 0; urla->domain[i] && urlb->domain[i]; i++)
    {
        int cmp = (int)urlb->domain[i] - (int)urla->domain[i];
        if (cmp != 0)
        {
            return cmp;
        }
    }
    if (urla->domain[i] == '\0' && urlb->domain[i] != '\0')
    {
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; urla->uri[i] && urlb->uri[i]; i++)
    {
        int cmp = (int)urlb->uri[i] - (int)urla->uri[i];
        if (cmp != 0)
        {
            return cmp;
        }
    }
    if (urla->uri[i] == '\0' && urlb->uri[i] != '\0')
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This file compiles without errors as C code, so be sure that you compile it as C. If you need to compile it as C++, then add explicit cast to `char*` at `payload` parameter in this line:

```
if (!WinDivertHelperParsePacket(packet, packet_len, &ip_header, NULL,
                NULL, NULL, &tcp_header, NULL, &payload, &payload_len) ||
            !BlackListPayloadMatch(blacklist, payload, (UINT16)payload_len))
```

Like this:

```
if (!WinDivertHelperParsePacket(packet, packet_len, &ip_header, NULL,
                NULL, NULL, &tcp_header, NULL, &payload, &payload_len) ||
            !BlackListPayloadMatch(blacklist, (char*)payload, (UINT16)payload_len))
```